# Verify to apply de L'hopital ($x\to x_0$)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I have done a similar question but referred to a limit for $x\to\infty$.
Now I have to prove the hierarchy of infinite applying de l'hopital theorem to the following limit.

$$\lim_{x\to0} x\log{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\log{x^2}}{1/x}$$
To apply de l'Hopital I have to verify:
$\log{x^2}$ and $1/x$ are differentiable in a neighbourhood of $0$. What is the neighbourhood that I have to consider? For instance can I take $(0,\infty)$?

**EDIT: I have read now that the two functions must be differentiable in an interval (a,b) except al least the point $x_0$, is it right?**

Comment: Any neighborhood works, and that neighborhood may exclude $0$ (or wherever you're taking the limit to).

Comment: I think it must be a two-sided neighborhood. $(0,\infty)$ is only one one side of the point we approach.

Comment: @311411 actually this was my doubt...what neighbourhood do you take in this case?

Comment: For this problem, there is no trouble, since both $x \mapsto \log x^2$ and $x \mapsto 1/x$ are defined and differentiable for all non-zero $x$. You can use neighborhood $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ or $(-0.001,0)\cup(0,0.001)$.

Comment: but from the theorem I have read that the neighbourhood must be an interval, right?

Comment: I do not know, because I haven't seen your theorem. I am using the theorem: If $|D(x)|\to\infty$ as $x \to 0$, and $N'(x)/D'(x) \to \alpha$ as $x \to 0$, then $N(x)/D(x) \to \alpha$ as $x \to 0$. For my theorem, I only need the derivatives to exist in a punctured neighborhood, some $(-\delta+0,0+\delta)$.

Comment: sorry but $(-\delta+0,0+\delta)$ in my excercise does not work...

Comment: @311411 do you mean what i have added in EDIT?

Comment: I would write instead "in an interval except possibly at the point $x_0$". But what I think you should do is edit your question to show the rule or theorem from your book. Maybe we need a different approach, since my theorem may not be allowed for you to use. But in any case $\log(x^2)$ and $1/x$ are not differentiable at zero.

Comment: ok I agree. The last question: exept possibly the point $x_0$ means that in $x_0$ they can be not differentiable, but then how can I compute the limit of the derivative for $x\to x_0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we have $$\frac{N(x)}{D(x)}=\frac{\log(x^2)}{\frac1x}$$ and we wish to find the limit as $x$ approaches zero. (This method will also work for problems in which $x\to x_0\not=0$ is considered.)

We can look at the limit of the ratio of derivatives: $$x\not=0:\quad\quad\frac{N'(x)}{D'(x)}=\frac{\frac1{x^2}\,2x}{-\frac1{x^2}}=-\frac2x\;x^2=-2x \to 0. $$ Because $|D(x)|\to\infty$ as $x$ goes to zero, we may conclude $$\frac{N(x)}{D(x)}=x\log(x^2) \to 0.$$

Comment: Ok so do you have use the theorem even if the single derivatives does not exist in 0, right?

Comment: Yes, we may use the theorem. It does not bother us that the individual derivatives fail to exist at zero. But it is crucial that $N'(x)$ and $D'(x)$ exist for all $x$ in some punctured neighborhood of $x_0$. Punctured neighborhood is also called deleted neighborhood, and will have the form $(-\delta+x_0,\,x_0 + \delta)$ for some positive $\delta$.

Comment: @pawel is everything here clear to you?

Comment: Yes very thanks! @311411